# RoR: Creating a relationship between a purchased product and a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hello and thanks for any help in advance.

I want to create a relationship between a user and a product(pdf) upon an order being saved.

```
class PDF
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :pdf
  belongs_to :cart
end

class Cart
  has_many :line_items
  has_one :order
end

class Order
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

Upon the user purchasing a line_item, I would like to create relationships through a join model between user and pdf (pdf_relationships).

I'm trying to find each PDF(found by foreign_key line_item.pdf_id) in a given cart and create pdf_relationships between a user and each pdf in the cart. I'll be making the user's id the owner id and making the pdf's id the owned_id.

My order controller looks like this:

```
def create 
  @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
  @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  if @order.save
    if @order.purchase
      render :action => "success"
    else
      render :action => "failure"
    end
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

and what I'm having trouble with is this:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :cart

  before_save :create_owner

  ***def create_owner
    self.cart.line_items.each do |item|
      pdf.find_by_item_pdf_id(:pdf_id)
      current_user.pdf_relationships.build(:owned_id => pdf.id)
    end
  end***
end
```

here is my user model:

```
   class User
  has_many :line_items

  has_many :pdf_relationships, foreign_key: :owner_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :pdfs, foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pdf_ownings, :through => :pdf_relationships, :source => :owned

 def owning?(owned)
    pdf_relationships.find_by_pdf_owned_id(owned)
  end

  def own!(owned)
    pdf_relationships.create!(:owned_id => owned.id)
  end

  def unown!(owned)
    pdf_relationships.find_by_pdf_owned_id(owned).destroy
  end
```

I hope this is clear enough. I've been trying to figure this out for sometime now and definitely trying to get past being just a novice. Suggestive readings are definitely welcome too!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea.

Since `LineItem` has many `PDF`s, you can just use the `pdf_id` from the `LineItem` without bothering to fetch the record from the database. You can also append those IDs to the existing set of user-PDF associations as if you were just pushing items onto an array.

However, your model won't have access to the current session (since that's handled by the controller), so you'll have to pass the current user to the `Order` some other way, perhaps as part of the `purchase` method.

```
class Order
  belongs_to :cart

  def purchase(user)
    # ... existing logic ...

    user.pdf_relationship_ids << cart.line_items.map(&:pdf_id)
  end
end
```

You will also have to declare the association between `User` and `PDF` and create the migrations, but it sounds like you're already planning to do that.

---

**Update:** I think you can greatly simplify your `User` model by taking advantage of `has_many :through`. Here's what I envision:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :line_items, :through => :orders
  has_many :pdfs, :through => :line_items
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :pdf
end

class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
end
```

Then you don't have to explicitly specify that a user owns a PDF. It's implicit in the user -> order -> line item -> PDF relationship.

This may not solve your problem as-is. You wouldn't be able to "disown" a PDF without deleting the original line item, which is probably not what you want. But I think you should try to aim for something like this. Take advantage of Rails's built-in associations as much as you can.

Comment: I figured I must've been going in right direction. I guess the problem comes in when I try to find the pdf by iterating through each line_item (cart.line_item.pdf_id.each...) in the cart and looking at each line_item.pdf_id. Once I get those ids, then I can create the pdf relationship. Overall, I need to take each pdf.id which is line_item.pdf_id and place that as owned.id.

Comment: Are you still getting an error? Were you able to use my sample code? If not, what does your `User` model look like?

Comment: Yea I'm still getting error. I edited my question and added user model. Is my code for def create_owner in order model even remotely correct?